# Longest simple path between given two vertices in an undirected graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory, theory, np

> **Input:** *n-node undirected graph **G(V,E)**; nodes **s** and **t** in V; positive integer **k***
>
> **Question:** *Is there a simple path between s and t in G that contains at least k edges?*

I know this problem is NP-hard but the thing is how and with which algorithm, should I approach to this question?

I have used BFS algorithm so far but I think its not the one that I should go with. At this point I don't know how to continue. I'm not very sure if I can find a solution for this question or not. An approximation would do too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be solved with a variation of BFS: instead of storing nodes in the queue, store paths. The other difference is that instead of ignoring nodes which are already visited, we only ignore nodes if they are already included in the current path.

- Initialise a queue with a single path, containing just the node `s`.
- While the queue is non-empty:

  - Poll a `path` from the queue. Let `u` be the last node in the path.
  - If `u = t`:

    - If the number of nodes in `path` is at least `k + 1`, then `path` is a solution; return with the result "true".
  - Otherwise if `u != t`:

    - For each neighbour `v` of `u` which is not already in `path`, construct a new path by appending `v` to `path`, and insert it into the queue.
- If the loop terminates without finding a solution, then none exists; return with the result "false".

The exact same solution works using DFS instead of BFS, by replacing the queue with a stack. In that case the stack will usually use less memory, but won't necessarily find the shortest solution. Since you just want to answer true/false if such a path exists, finding the shortest is unnecessary, so DFS is probably better.

Comment: I did modified the BFS very similar to what you said. It really works and thanks for the explanation also for an alternative method. I generated a bunch of random graphs with different number of vertices and edges as test cases(100,200,500,1000,2000 graphs). After that I used BFS method with these graphs. But when I use a graph with 12 vertices or above the program keeps running and does not give any outputs. I used 100 graphs with 15 vertices as input and waited for about 8-9 hours but the program was still running. Is that normal ?

Comment: The time complexity should be something like n^k in the worst case, so if you're looking for paths of length k = n - 1 or near that, then it will ramp up very quickly, yes.

Comment: I have some question marks about complexity of the algorithm but I will figure it out myself. Your explanation helped me a lot. Thanks for the help, I appreciate it. @kaya3